# Python: "Cannot close a running event loop" Asyncio

Tags: python, loops, twitter, web-scraping, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import Twper

async def main():
    q = Query('Some Query Goes Here', limit=20)
    async for tw in q.get_tweets():
        # Process data
        print(tw)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

When I run it, I get the message:

> File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 94, in
>   close
>       raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")

What can I do, to use Twper properly and scrape tweets?

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'Query' is not defined` instead. The `loop.close()` error is just masking this I suspect

Comment: try to restart the kernel

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close a running loop without stopping it first. Try doing:

```
loop.stop()
time.sleep(1)
loop.close()
```

Comment: Is it necessary to sleep the program for a second? Can the loop not be closed immediately after stopping?

Comment: I tried and the error continues. It is not clear to me how `close` should handle. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=close#asyncio.loop.close) does not shows how manage the `RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop` error :\.